# New lawn not rolled, just mud

Tags: lawn

The contractor we used did not level the 4 to 6 inches of topsoil after seating. Because our property is sloped the grass is now almost 6 inches high, but we cannot get on it to mow it because you just sink in the mud. What do we do? We are in zone five, I believe, so frost will be coming soon. Do we wait until spring? What do we do with this long grass that we cannot get cut?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the "topsoil" ("fill" might be a better word) that your contractor used rather than lack of rolling. They possibly used a heavy silt soil instead of field (top) soil. At a project where I live, they used soil from a drainage ditch to backfill behind the new curb-and-gutters - it's very thick, sticky, and pasty when wet and rarely dries out, but when it does dry out it's like concrete.